# ARCore – "This device does not support AR" on Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm using a `Pixel 4` as a virtual device running API 30. I've set the back camera to virtual scene and I've also installed Google Play Services for emulator.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: I think you need real device : https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices

Answer (score 2):

### Try API 29

This problem often occurs when you're running API 30 (or even API 33). Try API 29.

And if you're running `Android Emulator` on macOS, there's one more issue:

> **macOS with ARCore SDK 1.16.0 or later**: Due to a known issue, Android Emulator `x86_64` system images are not supported on macOS with ARCore SDK 1.16.0 or later. As a workaround, use an `x86` system image.

Comment: Still an issue in September 2022, I was using API 33 and had to go back to API 29